# translating wordpress with poedit

Tags: translation

im trying to translate twenty ten based child theme,  I have modifided the single-loop.php with a custom snippet, that shows next and previous arrows...

my issue is that this string (next and previous text) **cant be translated**... the replacement doesnt occur with this specific string. I do all the process of detecting the string and creating all with poedit, but does not work. all other strings do translate OK.

I edited the php file single-loop.php:

```
<?php add_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'my_custom_post_navigation', 4, 99); ?>
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous">
        <?php next_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav"> %link </span>', __( '&#9668; Previous','Previous post link', 'category','twentyten') , TRUE ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-next">
        <?php previous_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav"> %link </span>', __( 'Next &#9658;','Next post link', 'category', 'twentyten') , TRUE ); ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- #nav-above -->
<?php remove_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'my_custom_post_navigation', 99); ?>

<!-- END .featandnav  of Featured and Navigation container DIV  -->
```

-Then I scanned all the php files with poedit and the strings appear: I translated them (Next ► - and -◄ Previous) using poedit..

but then, even that I uploaded the files to the theme language folder, this string does not translate, 
as I mentioned before:
all the others original of the theme, do translate...

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are there four arguments in the translation string?  AFAIK; there should only be the translatable string, and the text domain as arguments `__('Next', 'twentyten')` or `__('Previous', 'twentyten')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at [next_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [previous_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link).  Specifically; how the function arguments are arranged.

Next, take a closer look at [translating strings](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers); and how the function arguments are arranged.

Now, when you put the two together; you should have something like this:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav"> %link </span>', __( '&#9668; Previous','twentyten'), TRUE ); ?>
```

And:

```
<?php next_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav"> %link </span>', __( 'Next &#9658;', 'twentyten'), TRUE ); ?>
```

The first argument of `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` is the html structure to display; the second argument is the string of text to use; the third argument is used to determine if you are staying within the same taxonomy when going back and forth.

Regarding the `__()` translation function; the first argument is the text string to be translated; and the second argument is the text domain (although this can vary depending on which localization function is being used).

Comment: Great :)  Always happy to help!!